# Why is staticpropertychanged null?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I develop an UWP application. I have a class Client which manage the connection to another application by sockets.

In my ViewModel class, I have a static property named TextConnect which is bind to a textbox in my View.

I want to display "Connected" in the textbox when the connection is established. So, my ViewModel class implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and I have a static EventHandler named StaticPropertyChanged that I used to notify the view that my TextConnect property changed :

`public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;`

And in my Client class I changed the value of this property when the connection is established :

`ViewModel.TextConnect = "Connected";`

The method which modifies the TextConnect property in my Client class runs in another thread.

But when I try to change the value of the property, I have an error which says that my event StaticPropertyChanged is null :

`System.NullReferenceException : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Why StaticPropertyChanged is null while my property is bind to my textbox ?

Comment: It is a very common beginners mistake, trying to share data via statics. You should avoid it as much as possible. | A class you have to instantiate, assigned to a static variable - that is about the closest I would ever get to that. But honestly. you should not need any static here. If you want to share data, that is why App.XAML is the root of your visual tree - so you got something shared between all Windows and VIew Models.

Comment: so I don't understand how to proceed then in my case to not have to use the static properties. Can you developp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to display "Connected" in the textbox when the connection is established. So, my ViewModel class implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and I have a static EventHandler named StaticPropertyChanged

If you want bind TextBox `Text` property with `ViewModel`'s `TextConnect` property,  TextConnect should be non-static, because we need to invoke [`PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged) in the set method (can not run in the static method). If you want to access `TextConnect` statically, you could make static `Current` property for the ViewModel. For the detail steps please refer the following code.

**Xaml**

```
<ToggleSwitch Header="This is header" IsOn="{Binding IsOpen}" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static MainPageViewModel Current;
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Current = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    private bool _isOpen;

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return _isOpen; }
        set { _isOpen = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
MainPageViewModel.Current.IsOpen = true;
```